# Table cells, created by iteration, are hidden - how to unreveal each entry with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have a table where one of the columns is a hidden field. The table is created by iterating over a database using jinja notation.

Currently, the button (to the right of each entry) only reveals-hides the first entry in the table, as the image below shows. e.g. Inc20 button is ‘toggling’ Inc15’s personal acc.

I would like:

1. The show button to hide-reveal toggle the Personal_acc in each table row
2. A ‘Show all’ button at the top to reveal/hide them all.

(Ideally the personal_acc wouldn’t be an `<input>`, but just regular text)

Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Income and Expenditure Ledgers{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
  <style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" class="article-title" 
href="{{ url_for('home', charity_id=charity_id) }}">Home</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" class="article-title" 
href="{{ url_for('CSVil', charity_id=charity_id) }}">Export to CSV</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary" class="article-title" 
onclick="myFunction()" style="float: right;">Show All</a>

  <h2>Income Ledger</h2>
  <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Personal_acc</th>
    <th>DRcode</th>
    <th>CR</th>
    <th>CRcode</th>
  </tr>
  {% for a in IL %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ a[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ a[1] }}</td>
    <td><input type="password" value={{ a[2] }} id="myInput">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" class="article-title" 
    onclick="myFunction()" >Show</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"                     data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ a[3] }}</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ a[7] }}</a></div></div>
    </td>
    <td>{{ a[5] }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"                     data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ a[6] }}</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ a[8] }}</a></div></div>
    </td>
    </tr>>

  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) 
You can change your function as follows:

```
var passwordsActive = true;

function myFunction() {
    passwordsActive = !passwordsActive;  
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".table input");
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].type = passwordsActive ? "password" : "text";
    }
}
```

1)
An id should be unique. If you iterate over a list, you can add an index to the id (or you can add the object id a.id)

```
id="dropdownMenuButton-{{idx}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc. I am fairly new to javascript. Would you mind helping me adapt your code for my html/js. I’m struggling to get it working Thank you.

Comment: To solve problem 2, you replace your code between <script> and </script>  with my code above  (var ...   } ) . Then you can try to click on the 'Show all' button.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve made the change, but it doesn’t seem to work. None of the Show buttons or show all buttons are doing anything.

Comment: Can you do a quick test and put this code in the webdevelooper console (browser) after rendering the page:                   
  var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".table input");
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].type = "text";
    }